# jQuery slideDown only section that has been clicked

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to reveal some content on click like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.extraClick').click(function(){

          $( ".extra" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {});

    });

});
```

```css
.extra {
    display: none;
}

.section {
    padding:10px;
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">

    <div class="container">
    
      <p>
          This is the section 1 content
      </p>
      
      <div class="extraClick">
          Click Me
      </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="extra">
         This is some extra content
    </div>

</div>

<div class="section">

    <div class="container">
    
      <p>
          This is the section 2 content
      </p>
      
      <div class="extraClick">
          Click Me
      </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="extra">
         This is some extra content
    </div>

</div>

<div class="section">

    <div class="container">
    
      <p>
          This is the section 3 content
      </p>
      
      <div class="extraClick">
          Click Me
      </div>

    </div>
    
    <div class="extra">
         This is some extra content
    </div>

</div>
```

But it is revealing all of the content, how can I get it to only reveal the extra content for the section that has been clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `$(this)` instead of `$(".extra")`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being clicked. Then use `.closest()` to navigate up the DOM to the `.section` div, and then `.find()` to navigate down the DOM to find the related `.extra` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.extraClick').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".section").find(".extra").slideDown("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.extra {
  display: none;
}

.section {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      This is the section 1 content
    </p>
    <div class="extraClick">
      Click Me
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra">
    This is some extra content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      This is the section 2 content
    </p>
    <div class="extraClick">
      Click Me
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra">
    This is some extra content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      This is the section 3 content
    </p>
    <div class="extraClick">
      Click Me
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="extra">
    This is some extra content
  </div>
</div>
```